# Can SharePoint objects like 'SP.ClientContext' be used while developing Office 365 Mail Addin in Napa?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, jsom, napa

I am developing a Office 365 Mail Addin in Napa. I am trying to use the object of `SP.ClientContext` but it shows me error that `SP is not defined`.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        app.initialize();

        var context = new SP.ClientContext("https://mysite.sharepoint.com/"); // <-- Error
        var web = context.get_web();
    });
};
```

I would like to know can SharePoint objects like `SP.ClientContext`, `SP.Web`, etc. be used while developing Office 365 Mail Addin in Napa? If yes, then what is the best approach for the same?

**Update 7 Aug 2015:**

The Napa editor for the code `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', Office.initialize);` shows error as

> 'SP' is not defined

[image: Screenshot of error in Napa editor]

While executing the code in the Google Chrome's console I see the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined

[image: Screenshot of error in Google Chrome console]

The conclusion I arrive at here is that - the SharePoint file `sp.js` is simply not available to Office Mail Addin. For this I probably need to download `sp.js` and upload in my Main Addin which would be quite inefficient. Is there any way to reference `sp.js` of Office 365 in Office Mail Addin? For a SharePoint app the path is `/_layouts/15/sp.js`. So what would be the path for Office Mail Addin?

Comment: see this if it helps https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/accessing-office-365-sharepoint-sites-using-rest-from-a-local-html-javascript-host/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use it in Napa while developing the app, if it is not getting reference of sp.js from sharepoint itself you can add external sharepoint api.

```
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sharepointplus/3.0.10/sharepointplus.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: The library you referring in your answer is [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) and *not* SharePoint's `sp.js` which resides in `/_layouts/15/sp.js`. That is the file in need to refer to. The API calls of SharepointPlus is completely different from `sp.js`

Comment: I understand it is different but it will resolve your problem just take a try.